# JavaScript: How can I get code as String?

Tags: javascript

I have this object:

```
 { tag: 'button',
   attrs: { onClick: this.myFunc },
   children: 'Name' }
```

This object is in a context where `this.myFunc` is a function.
How can I get `this.myFunc`?

If I try with: `obj['attrs']['onClick']` it prints all of the function:

```
function(event){...}
```

Comment: Are you trying to call the function?

Comment: @kinakuta no, I want get as string: "this.myFunc"

Comment: Well, I'm not sure how you're going to get it as a string unless you convert the object to JSON then parse it to find what follows the "onClick:" portion of the string

Comment: @kinakuta For good reasons JSON will not support functions.

Comment: Why are you trying to do so? Where / how is the object defined? As far as described it will not be possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried this to get the function name as a string

```
obj.attrs.onClick.name;
```

This would most likely return "myFunc" and not "this.myFunc" though, just depends what you want.

Comment: @joe I reverted your edit because 'String' vs 'string' is not a grammar issue in JavaScipt, but they refer to different types with 'string' being the primitive and most likely correct one here

Answer (score 0):

If you want just to get the name, you may want to try this:

```
var name = /function ([^(]*)/.exec( obj['attrs']['onClick']+"" )[1];
```

Comment: Try it now please @granmirupa